# Is it possible to access a superclass's superclass in flex/as3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to override a subclass's method but I think I need access to the superclass one higher up in the hierarchy. So I'd like to do something like super.super.methodName();

FYI, the actual problem I'm trying to solve should be explained by my code below:

```
public class A extends UIComponent{
    override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        super.keyDownHandler(event);

        if(event.keyCode==46)
            remove();

    }
}

public class B extends A{
    override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

        if(event.keyCode==46 && removeable==true)
            remove();
                    else
                super.super.keyDownHandler(event);

    }
}
```

If I use the class A's KeyDownHandler method, you will see that remove() is called regardless. However, the docs state that I need to call UIComponent.keyDownHandler whenever I subclass UIComponent. Of course this works for the first subclass, but not that subclass's subclasses.

I realise that I could put the functionality all into A with something like
    if(this is B){...}
but that seems to me to be a hack.

Comment: Although this would be a clever way to access your super's super class's methods, I think this could get confusing really quickly. If this is to override some of the built-in Flex UIComponent method... I can see some advantage to it, but quite frankly I think method-names should just be organized so you can call the UIComponent's keyDownHandler directly instead of through a "super-chain". I'm just recommending to use distinctive method-names for each cases IF you intend to share this code with others. Otherwise, it looks like a nice little challenge to get into :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add another method to class A, let's call it superKeyDownHandler whose only purpose would be to call some method from superclass.

```
protected function superKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    super.keyDownHandler(event);
}
```

And then what you want to achieve would be as easy as calling

```
super.superKeyDownHandler(event);
```

This is just a way around however not the actual clean solution, so use it at your own risk :)

**UPDATE:**

Something maybe cleaner would involve overriding keyDownHandler content of class A. So in class A you would have:

```
public class A{
    override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        super.keyDownHandler(event);
        overridableContent();
    }

    protected function overridableContent(){
        //do class A specific things here
        if (event.keyCode==46)
            remove();
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    override protected function overridableContent(){
        //do class B specific things here
        if (event.keyCode==46 && removeable==true)
            remove();
    }
}
```

Calling something like `new B().keyDownHandler(event)` now will cause calling keyDownHandler as it is defined in class A with content taken from class B.

Comment: I think your update suits what I'm trying to do in the most readable way. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

What I gather from your question is that, you want to use the functionality given by the superclasses' superclass, and not by the superclass itself.
Am I right cammil?

Comment: You should use comments to post comments, and answers to answer a question. Yours is not an answer...